# Retornar Data y View en JsonResult

Tags: c#, json, mvc

Los pongo en contexto, estoy trabajando con C# arquitectura MVC, a la hora de realizar el POST de un Create, definido de la siguiente manera:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult Create(List<Modelo> registros)
 {...
```

Debo retornar un `JsonResult()` en el cual debo devolver los datos (Data) y a su vez recargar la View en la cual estoy realizando este Post con el dato ya cargado.

Tengo realizado el siguiente Json:

```
return new JsonResult() { Data = new { Ok = true } };
}
```

El problema es que no sé como devolverle también la View actual(Post "Create") en este mismo **return Json**.

Un saludo, estoy a disposición ante cualquier duda sobre la pregunta planteada.

Comment: No interpreto bien que es lo que buscas hacer

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal retornar en un mismo JsonResult(), Data y la misma vista del Post (Create). seria algo como. 
return new JsonResult() { Data = new { Ok = true } }; *+*  return Redirect("Create");

Comment: no retornas view cuando usas json como respuesta, ya que lo que devuelves es un json y no html, se supone que el html ya lo estas visualizando y debes usar javascript o jquery para asignar los datos que recibes de la llamada ajax

Comment: Me parece que buscas un comportamiento similar al de WebForms, pero MVC es bastante diferente. Cuando haces el POST y recibes el Json, YA estas en la vista (pagina), no necesitas recargar nada. Lo unico que necesitas (como bien anota @LeandroTuttini) es leer los datos dentro del Json y volver a pintar los elementos del DOM que correspondan

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que querés es enviar una form a una View Create tenes que crear el controller

`[HTTPGet]
 public ActionResult Create()..`

y usar lo que te devuelve la ajax call desde esa view, JsonResult solo devuelve json